# Cannot override X-Frame-Options with Apache/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, x-frame-options

I'm working within Facebook (with the Koala gem) and finally have to deal with a user having changed their password.  While it may not be the best interaction, my app catches the authentication change and presents the user with a link to click to reauthorize.  Clicking the link correctly hits FB and the redirect delivers the expected auth_code.  HOWEVER, the page delivered in response to the FB redirect is returned with X-Frame-Options set to DENY with the result that the user never sees the re-authentication results.

I'm lost as to why the X-Frame-Options are set to DENY.

I have tried setting the X-Frame-Options to SAMEORIGIN from within the Rails (3.2.6) application by adding the following line to the action:

```
response.headers['X-Frame-Options'] = 'SAMEORIGIN'
```

No luck.

I have also tried adjusting the response headers via Apache.  I have tried setting the X-Frame-Header for the entire site as well as targeting the specific urls that could be affected.  The current configuration looks like this (redacted):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName xx.xx.com
   DocumentRoot /apps/fb-publisher/current/public
   PassengerRuby /home/ubuntu/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/ruby
   ... SSL config ...
   <Location ~ "/publisher/(revalidate|new)">
      Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
   </Location>
   <Directory /apps/fb-publisher/current/public>
      ...
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My attempt here is to force the X-Frame-Options to SAMEORIGIN for  xx.xx.com/publisher/new and xx.xx.com/publisher/revalidate.  I have tried separate Location and LocationMatch blocks that target the individual URLs in addition to the current configuration.  I have also tried using Header unset (rather than set) to remove the X-Frame-Options however it's being set.

So far as I can tell these are the ONLY urls in the application that are returning the X-Frame-Options header set to DENY.

Ideas?

Comment: were you able to fix this? I am facing a similar issue where sometimes I get DENY and some time there is no X-Frame-Options key itself. DENY causes a problem. Here is the question which I have [posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39509786/rails-3-app-showing-different-values-for-x-frame-options-in-response-header).

Comment: Unfortunately I did not get an answer to this problem and I've moved on from the project.

Comment: I was finally able to fix this today, the code written in the application.rb file or controller was not helping at all, finally came to know that someone had added an header in ngnix.conf file in server, with DENY value, and by changing that to SAMEORIGIN I was able to fix it. Spent almost 4days on this issue.